# jQuery working fine locally but not on iis

Tags: jquery, iis-7.5

I running jQuery on my local website which works just fine. However, when I try to run that same exact website on a remote web server, the jquery just doesn't work. I am not getting any javascript errors.

Here is what I'm simply trying to do:
When I run my website locally or even when I run it locally pointing to my staging server, it works just fine as I explained. However, if I try and run it from the actual staging server, when clicking the "Generate PDF" button, it doesn't kick off the process. It's as if the value is coming back false and not executing the part I need to be executed or the js is simply not being executed. I triple verfified that the js is NOT commented out. It disables the button, but no activity. Is there anything I need to do implement or set up on the staging server?

Here is my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.blueopal.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
</head>
```

Index View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btnRefresh').click(function () {
        Refresh();
    });

    function Refresh() {

        var LoanID = $("#LoanID").val();

        if (parseInt(LoanID) != 0) {
            $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(false)
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
        else {
            alert("Please enter a LoanId");
        }
    }

    $('#btnGeneratePDF').click(function () {
        DisableGeneratePDF();
        $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true)
    });

    function DisableGeneratePDF() {
        $('#btnGeneratePDF').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#btnRefresh').attr("disabled", true);
    }

</script>
```

Controller:
When coming back from the js, the model.ShouldGeneratePdf value appears to be false when it should be true.

```
 if ((submitbutton == "Refresh") || (submitbutton == null) && (model.ShouldGeneratePdf == false))
```

Comment: I guess your problem is not on the javascript itself. But in the deployment of your website. Make sure everything was deployed ok.

Comment: Are you sure that the function is even returning anything at all? My thoughts are that the DOM is not ready when you bind the click function, so the element never has the click handler attached.  `<script></script>` and wrap it in a `$(function(){ //code });` [fiddle showing example](http://jsfiddle.net/HKayT/)

Comment: You should use the @url.Content("") syntax, refering all your js files, I reckon the url is not resolved on the server.

Comment: Everything was deployed OK. I triple checked it... I will check into the other two comments now....

Comment: I added the @url.Content("") syntax like so, but still doesn't work.

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I even tried to wrap it in a function and still didn't work as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem faced once.

What you should make sure first,

All JS/JQuery required files are included on the hosting server.

Try using this type of statement to refer to source files, ResolveClientUrl("~/folder/js.js").

I believe this solves problem. If further not, then you can try changing the position of the JScode, once in the head section and try if it works, if not try it in the body section, you may try it in the start of the body and one time at the end of the body tags.

If this works, this is good, otherwise, no idea at the moment.

Comment: What would be the exact syntax of the ResolveClientUrl("~/folder/js.js") if I have the following: <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" </script> if the @url.Content("") syntax doesn't work?

Comment: Using the @url.Content("") syntax still didn't work for me. I'm at my witts end with this and can't figure out what else to try. I can't debug it, because it's on a remote web server. Anyone else have any ideas why this javascript is not executing?